# Why Span is breaking in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html

I was trying to make a website using bootstrap. When I tried to add some spans in the main content area [ Span5, Span5 and Sidebar Span2] Sidebar is breaking and comes to the next line 
I am attaching the CSS and browser preview.

It would be nice if someone has to help me in this regard

CSS Code:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="content-box">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="span5">
        Column1
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        Column2
      </div>
      <div class="span2">
        Sidebar
      </div>

    </div>
  </div><!-- End of "Row" -->

</div><!-- End of "Content Box" -->

</div><!-- End of "Container" -->
```

Thanks a lot

Teekeybee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bootstrap2, you need to wrap your nested `span`s with a `row` class:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-box">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="row"><!-- row for nested spans -->
                    <div class="span5">Column1</div>
                    <div class="span5">Column2</div>
                    <div class="span2">Sidebar</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your case, I think your `span12` is useless, so I suggest:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-box">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span5">Column1</div>
            <div class="span5">Column2</div>
            <div class="span2">Sidebar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Take a look to the doc ("Nested columns" part): http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap 3+, then span1, span2 are no longer valid. Please review their documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

I'm not familiar w/ bootstrap 2.3, but this is just in case you're using version 3+.