# bootstrap collapse span is breaking lines when it shouldn't be

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a difficulties with a bootstrap collapse button, I am trying to stop a line from breaking after the collapse button.

I saw this thread at [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826735/how-do-i-prevent-div-tag-starting-a-new-line) which gives the answer that I should be using span instead of div to stop the link from breaking but it doesn't work.

When I activate the collapse, it changes to the correct format(no line break) for a split second and it goes back to having a line break. Its mysterious because it is correct for a split second, before changing to the incorrect format. The process can be seen on [video](https://vimeo.com/269144856)

I have also tried using div class while making changes to style with "style="display: inline" but that doesn't work as well.

I trawled through stackoverflow to find a similar question at [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354283/why-span-is-breaking-in-bootstrap) but the answer they provided is to wrap a div class=row around my span which does not work at all. I am not sure why the answer to that question made sense since div class=row is for the purpose of breaking a new line.

Below is my snippet in html. I am running my app on django. Thanks for any advise anyone can give on this problem

```
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11" style="float:left">                    

              {% if poll.description %}
              <div class="Mobilefont Compfont">
                  <b class="reducesize">

                    {{ poll.description|striptags|safe|slice:":100" }}

                  <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=#{{poll}} style="padding:0px; margin:0px"><small><small><small>More</small></small></small></button>

                  <span id={{poll}} class="collapse">

                    {{ poll.description|striptags|safe|slice:"100:" }}

                  </span>

                    <small> - {{ poll.date|timesince }} ago</small></b>
              </div><br>
              {% endif %}

            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attached the below css style to fix the issue.

```
<style>

.reducesize
{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;

}
.reducesize .collapse.in{
     display: inline;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am Parshant.I  have seen your post on up work. I can fix this. The reason is that your span has large text which is difficult to fit in 100% container. There are 2 ways to solve this. 
>   Latest One: Just add 2 properties to your parent tag `<b class="reducesize"</b>`
>   `display:flex; align-items:flex-start;`
>
> Old Way: You have to define a width to each element & then float left etc.